# Got this error Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, amazon-dynamodb, angular7, dynamo-local

Got this error somebody help, want to display data on frontend, data is stored in dynamodb local database, I use get API call.
[image: angular]

[image: node server response]

display.component.html file

```
  <tbody>
      <h1> Testing</h1>

      <tr *ngFor="let thread of threads " >
          <td>{{ thread.threadId }}</td>
          <td>{{ thread.threadType }}</td>
          <td>{{ thread.createDate }}</td>
          <td>{{ thread.updateDate }}</td>
          <td>{{ thread.channelName }}</td>
      </tr>

  </tbody>
```

display.component.ts file

```
  threads : thread[];

  constructor(private bs: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bs.getthreads().subscribe((data: thread[]) => {
        this.threads = data;
    });
  }
}
```

data.service.ts

```
export class DataService {

  uri = 'http://localhost:4000/data';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getthreads() {
    return this
           .http
           .get(`${this.uri}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share your http response.

Comment: please show the console.log( this.threads)

Comment: try to get `data.body`

Comment: Farhat Zaman you mean get api?

Comment: console.log(data); and console.log(this,threads) both show data  in console , you can check screenshot Jacopo Sciampi

Comment: Artyom Amiryan please explain i cant get it

Comment: result["Items"] will solve your problem as you are trying to iterate the loop on object.

Comment: thanks to all issue solved , actually problem was with data i insert string data as object in dynamo db like "threadId" : {'s' : 1 } which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```js
 getthreads() {
    return this
           .http
           .get(`${this.uri}`)
           .map(result=>result["Items"]);
 }
```